# AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'all'

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib, seaborn

AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'all' for my Python Data Analysis
I'm trying to add the total number of fatalities from mudslide data given a certain country using pandas/matplotlib. Then I want to use seaborn to visualize that data on a barplot. However, whenever I do I get an AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'all' error. The CSV file I am using can be found here: and here is my code so far.

[CSV Data]https://data.nasa.gov/Earth-Science/Global-Landslide-Catalog/h9d8-neg4

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("dark")

csv = pd.read_csv('GLC03122015.csv')
count = csv[csv['country'].str.contains('Mexico|United States|Canada', na = False)]

#sns.scatterplot(x=count.country, y=csv.fatalities, data=csv)
sns.barplot(x=count.country, y=csv.loc[csv['country'].isin(['Mexico', 'United States', 'Canada']), 'fatalities'].sum(), data=csv)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi, could you specify at what line of your code the error is raised?

Answer (score 0):

You ended up passing a constant (`342`) to the `y` parameter, when the [`barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html) from Seaborn expects:

> Parameters: x, y, hue : names of variables in data or vector data, optional

As an alternative you could use the filter version of the dataframe you already have (`count`) and use Pandas [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group the `fatalities` by country, then, `sum` the fatalities for each country and plot with `sns.barplot`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("dark")

csv = pd.read_csv('GLC03122015.csv')
count = csv[csv['country'].str.contains('Mexico|United States|Canada', na = False)]

country_sum = count.groupby('country')['fatalities'].sum()
sns.barplot(x=country_sum.index, y=country_sum.values)
plt.show()
```

[image: country_landslide]